# Divide `/` partition to equal halves in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted, root

I have a `/` partition of 483G. I want the partition to be resized to 2 equal sizes. I am using `gparted` but is unable to divide. I am using ubuntu 14.04lts. What about the content in the existing partition if i resize `/` partition?
Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Using `gparted` how? From the system itself? An Ubuntu live session? Or a gparted live dvd? 1 thing: you can NOT edit partitions that are in use.

Comment: using `gparted` from system itself. I read that we can resize `/` partition by live ubuntu CD. I am a newbie here, so could not understand the 'live Ubuntu CD' thing.

Comment: You need to use the DVD you use to install Ubuntu.

Comment: What about the content in the existing partition?

Comment: Data in the partition should be untouched, but it is alway better to backup important data first, just for the case something goes wromg...